# Demodulating 7x Sequential BFSK Signals

Tags: demodulation, gnuradio, fsk

I'm hoping someone could help me find a demodulation approach to an FSK signal contained in wav files that has 14 unique, and evenly spaced channels. They appear to be separated into 7 BFSK pairs. I.E. the source will emit energy on either channel 0 or 1, then either 2 or 3, 4 or 5, and so on. It never emits energy on both channels in a pair simultaneously. After it has emitted energy at either 12 or 13, it circles back to either 0 or 1. The channel spacing is roughly 100Hz. This pattern continues until the end of transmission.

I've taken several stabs at demodding this signal, and have been scouring the internet and wrestling with gnuradio for weeks to no avail. I'm nearly at my wit's end and could really use some help.

Comment: Weird.  It sounds like symbol clock recovery is going to be a hassle unless you can treat the entire signal as 14-FSK.  But that brings its own hassles.

Comment: Ha! Not going to contradict Andy on anything sync ;) but I'll start with this: we could come up with a scheme where resampling to 14×channel spacing, followed by "elegantly undersampling" (by 7 or 14) leads to a single stream of symbols that one could use to do timing and (fine) frequency recovery; but it'd require pretty accurate knowledge of the channel spacing. Say, the symbol rate, it's not per chance something like 100/7 Hz?

Comment: (my guess is that channel spacing and symbol rate are intrinsically linked, and that recovering one exactly gives you the other exactly, which then allows you to move on)

Comment: Appreciate the ideas! My next attempt is going to be combining 2x7 channels into two single channels and then and feeding those through a binary slicer - will update on progress

Comment: @MarcusMüller Slick idea with the undersampling to fold it all down into 1 channel.  Nice!  You might end up inverting the symbols from every other channel (and hence every other symbol time) that way, but maybe the transmitter has already accounted for that.

Comment: @AndyWalls yep; even so, that would at worst be a bit flip in fixed positions, so a bit of gratuitous line coding ;)

Comment: My first thought is to deramp (with a sampled ramp of the 7 evenly spaced frequencies): sinc dramping to start of ramp (which would be easier to do) and then once aligned demodulate as standard 2-FSK.

Comment: ah if I understand you correctly, simply consider this a bit of an "unclean" stepped-frequency chirp, and sync to that, then de-chirp